Does girallon's blessing cast with beast claws mean a druid has 6 limbs and 4 attacks as a cat?
My druid is an alternate class shapeshift Player's Handbook II pg. 39. If I cast Girallon's Blessing (Spell Compendium pg. 106) in human form and shift to Warrior form will I retain the extra claws?

You may be interested in this question.

By “change to a cat,” I presume you mean predator form?

Hi, I edited your question because shapeshift is on pg. 39 of PHB2, not the original PHB. I also made the SC citation a little clearer. But one thing I’m still not clear on is “Warrior form”—the forms available to shapeshift are predator, aerial, ferocious slayer, forest avenger, and elemental fury. I’m pretty sure it doesn’t matter but it would be clearer if you use the same term PHB2 does. If it helps, “predator form” is the 1st-level one, and probably the one you mean. Finally: if my answer doesn’t answer your question, could you let me know what you still need?

Yes
Shapeshifting does not dispel or suppress spells, so girallon’s blessing and beast claws will definitely still be active effects on the druid.
The rule that comes closest to causing a problem is this:

Sometimes, one spell can render a later spell irrelevant. For example, if a wizard is using a shapechange spell to take the shape of an eagle, a polymorph spell could change her into a goldfish. The shapechange spell is not negated, however, and since the polymorph spell has no effect on the recipient’s special abilities, the wizard could use the shapechange effect to take any form the spell allows whenever she desires. If a creature using a shapechange effect becomes petrified by a flesh to stone spell, however, it turns into a mindless, inert statue, and the shapechange effect cannot help it escape.

(Player’s Handbook, pg. 172)
This wording isn’t the most clear that it could be, but when polymorph turns the wizard into a goldfish, the wizard is no longer an eagle—and no longer has any of the eagle’s abilities. The wizard still has shapechange, though, and thus the ability (granted by that spell) to change into something else, whether that’s back into an eagle or into something else. When the wizard does so, they are no longer a goldfish (even though the polymorph effect is still active), and thus won’t start asphyxiating due to a need to breathe water. They don’t need to breathe water because they aren’t a goldfish any more. (If the shapechange effect ended before the polymorph, however, the wizard would return to being a goldfish unless or until something else did something about that.)
However, while shapeshifting changes the druid’s body (and thus something like polymorph would make shapeshifting irrelevant, or vice versa), neither beast’s claws nor girallon’s blessing does the same: both of those spells add features to your body. They can do that to your predator form just as easily as they can do it to your regular form, and work just fine. You end up as a cat with an extra set of forelimbs, for 6 total including your legs.
Note that you technically have six claw attacks: four from girallon’s blessing, and two from beast claws. However, since you only have four arms/forelimbs, you can only use four of them at a time. This is the same whether you are shapeshifted or not.

Do the arms and claws from the ongoing spells remain the same size they were when the spell was cast, regardless of the new form's size? Or does the form-changing effect adjust the ongoing effects to match the new form's size?

@HeyICanChan The claws update to the creature’s new size.

Likewise, if a creature uses enlarge or reduce person when a human then transforms into a cat, the creature transforms into an enlarged or reduced cat?

@HeyICanChan That gets into whether or not spells re-check target validity when the target changes, which nothing else so far has had to deal with since beast claws and girallon’s blessing don’t specify anything about the target’s type or other stats, but enlarge or reduce person do. For other size-changing effects without that concern, yes, the size-changing effect would continue to be active and would affect the new form, growing or shrinking it relative to its usual size.
